# Como somar o calculo de uma coluna somente até determinado dia para trás do mês atuas

Tags: mysql

estou com o seguinte problema:

Preciso somar os valores de uma coluna do começo do mês, até determinada data, mesmo que tenha mais dias no mês, por exemplo, se alterei os dados do dia 05/05/2023, preciso que me retorne com a soma dos dias anteriores até aquele dia.

Estou tentando realizar isso somente via mysql.

```
Select dias, calculado, prod from base where month(now()- 2023-05-05);
```

Mas ele retorna sem dados.

Obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: tenta detalhar melhor essa sua pergunta ai mas tipos de campos por exemplo mas Select dias, sum(calculado), prod from base where month(now()- 2023-05-05) group by dias, prod

Comment: Boa tarde Doa, primeiramente me desculpe por não adicionar mais detalhes, estou me aprofundando agora como Dev, nas próximas perguntas serei mais claro

Answer (score 0):

Para realizar a soma dos valores de uma coluna até uma determinada data no MySQL, você pode utilizar a função **SUM** em conjunto com uma cláusula **WHERE**. Para considerar somente os valores até uma data específica, você precisa utilizar a função **DATE_FORMAT** para formatar a data da coluna e compará-la com a data desejada.

Por exemplo uma consulta que realiza a soma dos valores da coluna calculado até a data 05/05/2023:

```
SELECT SUM(calculado) AS soma
FROM base
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(dias, '%Y-%m-%d') <= '2023-05-05';
```

Nesta consulta, dias é a coluna que contém as datas, calculado é a coluna que você deseja somar e '2023-05-05' é a data limite até a qual você quer realizar a soma. A função DATE_FORMAT é utilizada para formatar as datas da coluna dias no formato 'AAAA-MM-DD' e compará-las com a data desejada.

Comment: Boa tarde Luis, primeiramente me desculpe por não adicionar mais detalhes, estou me aprofundando agora como Dev, nas próximas perguntas serei mais claro, mas a ideia é realizar a conta de acordo com o mês que "estamos" por exemplo sempre dia 01 até o dia que foi inserido o dado no banco.

Comment: se for fazer uso de 2 períodos tente utilizar algo como                     
date_trunc('day', d.data_movimento) >= '2023-03-01'::date AND date_trunc('day', d.data_movimento) <= '2023-03-31'::date ou fazer uso de between